# I want to set an Access Policy for our external users, so what is the license needed

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, accesscontrol

We have an Office 365 tenant, but when i tried to define an access policy for unmanaged devices, i got this message:-

[image]

so what are the needed license and how i can get it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like the picture shows, you should get a subscription to Enterprise Mobility + Security E3 or Enterprise Mobility + Security E5 and assign a license to yourself To use this setting.

You could get it from here: [Enterprise Mobility + Security pricing options](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/microsoft-365/enterprise-mobility-security/compare-plans-and-pricing)